# i need to split sorted list, and make a new list out of it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

I have sorted a list, which has a dictionaries. sorted by 'a':

```
A = [{'a': 1,'c': 3}, {'a': 1,'c': 300},  {'a': 10,'c': 30}, {'a': 10,'c': 3000}]
```

I need to convert it into

```
[ [{'a':1,'c':3},{'a':1,'c':300}]  , [{'a':10,'c':30}, {'a':10,'c':3000}] ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your data is already sorted by the grouping key, you can handily use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for _, g in groupby(A, key=lambda d: d["a"])]
# [[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'c': 300}], 
#  [{'a': 10, 'c': 30}, {'a': 10, 'c': 3000}]]
```

You might go for even more utils with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

[list(g) for _, g in groupby(A, key=itemgetter("a"))]
```

Note that the `_` is just an anonymous variable (anonymous by convention) indicating that we are not using its value anywhere.